# How to sum two column with two diffrent tables

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi I want sum two columns (type double) with two diffrent tables. My query sql works until i add clauses "where". If every clausule "where" are met  then is okej, return correct result. If even one clause return null then result is null. What change my code to single clause return 0 if doesnt exist record.

`select (select sum(amount) from change_graphic where month(change_date)=4 and year(change_date)=2019)+(select SUM(provision)  from contracts where accepted=0 and month(date)=4 and year(date)=2019);`

Comment: `IFNULL((SELECT ...), 0)`

Comment: Please format your code reasonably. Read the edit help re code blocks. Please in code questions give a [mcve]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `coalesce()`:

```
select (select coalesce(sum(amount), 0)
        from change_graphic
        where month(change_date) = 4 and year(change_date) = 2019) +
       (select coalesce(sum(provision), 0)
        from contracts
        where accepted = 0 and month(date) = 4 and year(date) = 2019
       );
```

The subqueries are guaranteed to return one row, because they are aggregation queries with no `GROUP BY`.  Hence, you can convert `NULL` generated by the `SUM()` into `0` for the addition.

I would recommend that you approach the date comparisons as:

```
select (select coalesce(sum(amount), 0)
        from change_graphic
        where change_date >= '2019-04-01' and
              change_date < '2019-05-01' 
       ) +
       (select coalesce(sum(provision), 0)
        from contracts
        where accepted = 0 and 
              date >= '2019-04-01' and
              date < '2019-05-01' 
       );
```

This enables MySQL to use an index on the date column, if an appropriate index is available.